How do Enable a Win32 control with an attached action and run the OnExecute event remotely when the action is disabled? (in a Delphi application)
It's easy to enable a control using EnableWindow(Handle, True), which can be done from within an application or from an external application if you can determine the handle.  This allows you to enable a disabled button and click on it if there is code in the OnClick event.  This doesn't work if an action is attached to the button and the action is disabled.
Is there a way to enable an action in a similar way from an external application?

Essentially: no. You can use the Win32 API to communicate between Win32 applications, but the VCL is internal to each application. But of course you can implement your own facilities to handle things like this.

If the action is disabled it is probably disabled with a reason. Executing said action at this point could lead to unexpected behavior or errors.

Hey Alister I usually don't pay much attention of who is posting the question. But in this case I'm just puzzled of why would one of great teachers of programming in Delphi be asking such question. While quick search seems to indicate that you have talked about using Actions in only two of your videos (there might be more that I haven't found) I'm pretty sure that you know that the main reason of why someone would go using Actions is to decouple your program logic from UI. So why are you then looking for UI hack to hack Actions?

@SilverWarior I'm investigating the security of using actions.  If you put code in the OnClick event of a button (say), a third party can enable the button and "click" on it fairly easily (don't rely on disabling controls for application security).  I'm wondering if there is a way of doing the same if an action is attached.  I use Actions all the time and want to understand how safe they are better.

Unless your action handlers verify in which context they're executed they can easily be reassigned to anywhere else, circumventing all the action logic entirely. Watch your DFM in text just once, then realize that a compiled program just renders its Form upon that text, and as such it can be freely reordered by anyone. One hindrance could be to not assign any handler in the designer, but doing that during the Form's creation.

Actions are definitely safer than relying on state of standard visual controls. That is because since most standard visual controls rely on WinAPI it is possible to change their state using this same WinAPI. Actions on the other hand rely on on your application code so changing them requires injecting third party code into your application. But Actions are still potentially unsafe. Since desiign-time configurations of Actions is stored in DFM which then gets compiled into your application executable as resource it is possible to modify this DFM and by doing so affecting your actions. ...

... Combine this with the fact that Actions still rely on event based design it is pretty easy to sort of remap any action's OnExecute event method to some other control and fire it this way. That is unless you assign all of your Actions OnExecute event methods at runtime.

If target app was compiled with runtime packages enabled, than it will be easier to just enable action. In order to do so, one would need to compile separate dll, that will iterate over Screen.Forms, find necessary action and enable it. Most important thing is that this dll should be compiled in the same Delphi version with runtime packages enabled. When injected into target process (SetWindowsHookEx, etc.), it will be able to interact with anything accessible via global variables, such as Application or Screen. UI tests in RAD Studio work this way, but I haven't said that.
If target app was compiled without runtime packages, the task is much harder and bordering with hacking. Inside injected dll you can get pointer to the VCL object in the host app by using FindControl function. After that it should be possible to interact with this object using RTTI. But before doing anything, you need to somehow find address of GetMemoryManager procedure in the host's address space and replace MM in your dll with the one used by host. Most likely, after all manipulations, any attempt to unload dll will result in a crash of the host.
